# Regex to extract group of 2 numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I write a regex to extract `0, 78, 87` digits out the string of `"07887"`?

The output should look like this: `['0','78','87']`

(The rule is 1st number will be the single digit and following 4 digits should be grouped in group of 2)

Comment: what is the rule to separate the digits? otherwise I can only tell you to `print(['0','78','87'])`

Comment: The rule is 1st number will be the single digit and following 4 digits should be grouped in group of 2...

Comment: Wouldn't simple slicing work? `s = "07887"` then your output will be `[s[0], s[1:3], s[3:]]`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `textwrap`

```
import textwrap

my_string = "07887"

# First digit alone, the rest splitted by 2 characters.
my_list = [my_string[0], textwrap.wrap(my_string[1:], 2)]
```